# How to calculate percentage of an autosum field in excel

Tags: excel

I have a table which has a column with some numbers and cell containing the total value of those values in the last row which I have inserted with the AutoSum feature. I want to calculate the percentage of the number in one row of the total value. I'm doing this naively by clicking on a cell for the percentage and type `=` and then I click on the cell with the actual value, followed by typing `/` and finally clicking on the cell with the total value. What excel inserts as formula is:

```
=[@[Columnname]]/Table1[[#Totals];[Columnname]]
```

But when I hit enter excel tells that this is not a listed value.

How can I correctly address the last row's cell of this column? Note that even calling the cell with its current cell number (e.g. `C8`) results in the same message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem was, that I am using the "track tasks" template (don't know the name in english). It basically consists of a table that has a column with percentages. In the template those percentages are selected by the user from a drop down list. My modification should instead calculate those percentages. As the calculated values are not necessarily one of the drop down list values (5 in this case. 0, 25, 50, 75 and 100) and this is what excel means by "not a listed value".